# Unable to compile .cs file from regular command prompt, only Developer Command Prompt?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd, visual-studio-2015

I have this rather simple console application I developed using Visual Studio. With it, I have put together a simplistic C# program where using the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" I navigate to my directory and run "csc Program.cs" to compile the "Program.exe" file. From there I can type "Program ***" and pass a filename such as "Program file.asm".

Everything is working perfectly. However, I want to run this from the normal command prompt. When I compile within the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 the below two lines are output:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.3.1.60616
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

And when I navigate I can see that under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework I have folder options for:

- v1.0.3705
- v1.1.4322
- v2.0.50727
- v3.0
- v3.5
- v4.0.30319

When I do:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe C:\directory...\Program.cs

Output is:

**Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler Version 3.5.30729.5420 for Microsfot (R) .NET Framework version 3.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft COrporation. All rights reserved.**

**c:\Users\directory...\Program.cs(5,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Tasks' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

I then tried with v4.0.30319:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe C:\directory...\Program.cs

Which outputs:

**Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler Version 4.6.1055.0 for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft COrporation. All rights reserved.
This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
CSCD777AE6152014D6AAEC769E73B879B29.TMP: error CS1567: Error generating Win32 resource: Access is denied.
wrning CS1610: Unable to delete temporary file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CSCD777AE6152014D6AAEC769E73B879B29.TMP' used for default Win32 resource -- The system cannot find the file specified.**

Can anyone help me understand why this is all working fine for Developer Command Prompt but failing for regular command prompt even when fully quantifying the path for "csc.exe"?

Comment: if you do `set` in a normal command prompt and a dev command prompt,  you can see it sets up a lot more environment variables, as well as paths

Comment: Can you elaborate on `set`? EDIT: Nvm, I typed Set and see now. Is there an easy difference here for me to get the file to work in cmd prompt verus the Developer one?

Comment: go to a command prompt, type set, hit enter......  it will tell you what's setup in the environment.     do  set  >  a.txt   if you want to capture it to a file

Comment: comparing a normal cmd prompt with a dev one will show you all the things they setup

Comment: you can also run vsvars to set the enviroment.... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying quite a few things without understanding what is happening.

> I have put together a simplistic C# program where using the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" I navigate to my directory and run "csc Program.cs" to compile the "Program.exe" file.

When you run the C# compiler from this specific command prompt, `csc.exe` it is in the path. To find out what exact command is being run, on UNIX, we use a command called `which`. You can try gnu-utils or cygwin, or just manually iterate over all directories specified in the PATH (any case) variable to find out which exact path the csc.exe in question resides. This way you will know what is the exact path of the compiler.
**UPDATED**: You can use the `where` command on windows to find the full path of the command (Thanks to @ScottChamberlain)

> c:\Users\directory...\Program.cs(5,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Tasks' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

run `csc.exe /?` at the same prompt and see all the options that the compiler supports. One of them is `/r` for adding a reference to a dll

> When I do:
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe C:\directory...\Program.cs
>
> CSCD777AE6152014D6AAEC769E73B879B29.TMP: error CS1567: Error generating Win32 resource: Access is denied. wrning CS1610: Unable to delete temporary file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CSCD777AE6152014D6AAEC769E73B879B29.TMP' used for default Win32 resource -- The system cannot find the file specified.

You probably want to be in the directory of your file `Program.cs`. This way you have write permissions to the folder for generating necessary output files. You can also use the `/out` option to specify the output file name

> Can anyone help me understand why this is all working fine for Developer Command Prompt but failing for regular command prompt even when fully quantifying the path for "csc.exe"?

Most probably since the PATH environment variable is different. The Visual Studio Command Prompt, sets up a bunch of environment variable after starting the command prompt. You can see the difference in the environment between the two prompts by running the `set` command on both the terminals and doing a diff of their outputs. Needless to say, certain environment variables will always be different and that is not due to VS.NET

And as @KeithNicholas had mentioned in the comments, you can simply invoke `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio *\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` to set up your regular command prompt like visual studio command prompt

Comment: in windows `where csc.exe` will give you the path of the executed exe.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks. Did not know that. I have been using `where` on unix for ages, but never knew it worked on windows

Comment: `echo %~$PATH:1` in a batchfile will search the path and list the first one found for a filename as the only parameter. Include the full name ie notepad.exe. `batfile notepad.exe` will return `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`.

Comment: That's pretty much a "have you tried turning it off and on again" service desk type of answer, without any substantial analysis of the issue.